# How to detect window size with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i would like to check for the window size with jquery and based on the different resolutions i would like to change some css. This is the basic structure:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function checkWidth() {
    var windowSize = $(window).width();

    if ( windowSize > 600 ) {
    console.log('600px - 768px');

    } else if ( windowSize > 450 ) {
    console.log('450px - 600px' );

    } else if ( windowSize > 300 ) {
    console.log('300px -450px' );
    }

}

// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);

});
```

The problem is, i want to three condition with windowSize ( 300px-450px, 450px-600px, 600px-768px ). i do not know with the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
   function checkWidth() {
      var windowSize = $(window).width();

      if ( windowSize > 600 && windowSize <= 768 ) {
        console.log('600px - 768px');

      } else if ( windowSize > 450 && windowSize <= 600) {
        console.log('450px - 600px' );

      } else if ( windowSize > 300 && windowSize <= 450) {
      console.log('300px -450px' );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```js
checkSize();

function checkSize(){
var windowWidth = $(window).width(); 

if ( windowWidth >= 600 && windowWidth <= 768 ) {
        console.log('600px to 768px');

      } else if ( windowWidth >= 450 && windowWidth <= 600) {
        console.log('450px to 600px' );

      } else if ( windowWidth >= 300 && windowWidth <= 450) {
          console.log('300px to 450px' );
      }
}
        
$(window).resize(function() {
   checkSize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rzrzutkw/)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use CSS media queries?

```
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 449px) {
    /* your css properties */
}
@media(min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    /* your css properties */
}
@media(min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* your css properties */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but with media queries doesn't support with jquery.animate or click(function() { //code }); .

Answer (score -1):

With the below code, Based on different condition add your stuff.

```
$(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();    
    if(windowWidth == 300 || windowWidth == 450) {
       // add stuff
    }
    else if(windowWidth == 450 || windowWidth == 600) {
       // add stuff
    }
    else if(windowWidth == 600 || windowWidth == 768) {
       // add stuff
    }       
})
```